# Better way to implement a system that persist state per processing unit

Tags: architecture, state

In a message processing system, I have to persist the state of each message, so that the system could recover in case of a failure. 
For persisting the state, currently using a simple MySql database and have to persist the state per state change of every message.

Is there a better architectural pattern to design such a system or a way to persist states more efficiently ?

The system has to cater around 2000 messages per second with one message being around 1kb. Latency can be even 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you share more requirements? Performance, throughput, availability, volume of data per message, number of messages?

Comment: I do not understand why do you want additionally persist messages in a database? JMS messages for instance can be persistent (by default they are) so then it is the JMS broker, which ensures no messages are lost.